# Sort methods based on CamelCase

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea

Is there any IDE plugin (IntelliJ, Netbeans, Eclispe) or script that can sort methods on a class based on CRUD operations.

The method names are in CamelCase so I guess something that does not use the start of the method name when sorting.

For example sort Class methods by putting all CRUD method for specific Object together e.g.:

```
public void createBank(...)
public Bank readBank(...)
public void updateBank(...)
public void deleteBank(...)

public void createAccount(...)
public Account readAccount(...)
public void updateAccount(...)
public void deleteAccount(...)
```

Comment: I don't think any IDE can do that, your task is too specific. I think a script maybe is the best option you have. If you don't have hundreds of methods, maybe the fact is interesting to you that you can move your methods using drag&drop in Eclipse Outline view. A comfortable and safe way to sort methods by hand. Also, multi-selection drag&drop is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to rearrange the methods in CRUD order, but cannot find the way to group by object type.

```
public void createAccount() {
}

public void createBank() {
}

public Account readAccount() {
    return null;
}

public Bank readBank() {
    return null;
}

public void updateAccount() {
}

public void updateBank() {
}

public void deleteAccount() {
}

public void deleteBank() {
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Code Style > Java > Arrangement

There's a fixed set of grouping rules, which are not suitable, and no custom grouping rules are allowed.

[image]

Comment: Ya I also tried the IntelliJ Rearranger Plugin but it doesn't support seem to support regular expressions